# Implement TAP in MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, async-await

Apologies for asking a generic question, but I wanted a recommendation on the functionalities / areas in code where TAP (Task Async Programming) can be enabled for better performance.

I also use a Web API, where I can use async-await to retrieve data from database and do CRUD operations.

But do we have any guidelines or concrete ways of how to implement TAP in MVC C#.

Thanks In Advance!!!..

Comment: _can be enabled for better performance_ - asynchronous will not help with performance, but with availability.

Comment: Check out my response, that shall help in answering most questions you may have, revert back for any doubts you may still have

Answer (score 1):

> Apologies for asking a generic question, but I wanted a recommendation on the functionalities / areas in code where TAP (Task Async Programming) can be enabled for better performance.

Let's first understand, what is Asynchronous programming, it simply means taking the processing logic in the background while the main thread processing continues without getting blocked as in the case of the Synchronous processing, which blocks the calling thread, there are two kinds of Async processing:

1. `IO Async`, which is the primary use case, it is meant for any call outside the bounds of the process, like a call to database or a web service / web api, in this case **hardware based concurrency** comes in the picture since software threads are no more required, once call is dispatched over the network, software threads can go back to the thread-pool for serving other requests, thus increasing the system Scalability or availability as suggested by @Fabio. Role of the software threads is to dispatch the call and receive the results, there's no wait whatsoever, which is very quick < 1 ms in most cases, assuming no in-memory logic. Imagine there are only 25 threads in the pool for the synchronous call at best it can serve 50-100 requests, because wait pipeline will swell for the long running requests (few seconds), but for Async processing it is possible to dispatch 1000's of requests, as they are being dispatched over the network for processing, there's no wait literally for the thread pool threads to dispatch
2. `In Memory Async`, this is not the most common use case, but this is more about free the Ui thread, while a logical in memory processing can be taken in the background. It helps in keeping the interface responsive. In this case too Ui can be responsive as database call is done asynchronously, since synchronous calling invariably blocks the main thread, making the system non-responsive.

> What's the difference between Async and Parallel processing ?

Parallel processing is always in memory and is meant for utilizing all the computing power to process logic elements (preferably mutually exclusive) in parallel and aggregate the results in the end. It is meant to utilize all CPU processing power. In comparison Async processing is to take things in background and not to block the main processing thread, the in memory async, if Parallelized may still use CPU cores but otherwise it doesn't spike the CPU cores.

> I also use a Web API, where I can use async-await to retrieve data from database and do CRUD operations.

Web API are generally hosted on a web server like IIS, which has limited thread pool, and CRUD operations are DB calls outside the application boundary. As suggested above this is the ideal case for using the Async calls and increase system scalability.

> Design principles:

Can list few primary details:

1. In C# `async` methods needs to be prefixed by `await` operator
2. Complete chain from entry to exit needs to be enabled with `Async-Await`, if we miss it anywhere in between, then call will become Non-Async / Blocking, since actual thread is relieved only when there's dispatch over network for IO call and any other thread taking over for In memory call. Frameworks like MVC and WebAPI are enabled make the controller (entry point) async by default
3. For thread pool threads can use `ConfigureAwait(false)` to direct any pool thread to receive the result, it doesn't need to enter same Synchronization context, which is default, except for Ui thread, which cannot be replaced by any other thread (since its special and it can only the render the control).

> Conclusion

Same principles of `Async` apply in all the frameworks like `MVC,WebAPI,WCF,` since the same framework can make both `Async` and `Sync` calls, Asynchronous calling behave more like an aspect (cross-cutting), where threads can be directed to work in the Sync mode (blocking) or Async mode (non-blocking), thus increasing system `Scalability / Availability`